# What do you need to do Unit testing in Java with Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit

I've recently been lifted out of the .Net world into the Java world and I miss my unit tests.

Using Visual Studio I used NUnit and TestDriven.net to run my unit tests.

What is a comparable system for Java Using Eclipse?

I'm looking specifically for the plugins that will get me going, or a guide on how to do it.

I'm aware that JUnit is what NUnit was initially based on, but I want to know the best way to integrate it into Eclipse as there seem to be a few plugins that do this and I don't have the time to play around with them all.

**UPDATE**

Okay I didn't know that JUnit was built into the IDE. Are there any plugins that make using JUnit any easier?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using JUnit with eclipse is actually very easy.  Just go to File->New... and select JUnit Test Case.  Eclipse will handle adding the JUnit library and all of the imports.

Answer (score 4):

Which version of Eclipse are you using?

For as long as I remember (I've been using Eclipse since early 3.xs), Eclipse supports JUnit out of the box. You just:

Right-click on a project -> Run As -> JUnit Test

Does this not work for you?

Comment: I'm using Europa. And I didn't know that it was built into the IDE, thats pretty cool.

Comment: Unit Testing and refactoring IDE-support evolved like  Smalltalk > Java > .Net n the rest now

Answer (score 3):

I've been using [moreUnit](http://moreunit.sourceforge.net/) for a few years and can't live without its <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> shortcut to switch between the class and its test case.

I've also found [EclEmma](http://www.eclemma.org/) useful for finding untested code.

Answer (score 2):

Easier than "Right-click on a project -> Run As -> JUnit Test"?  Like you want it bound to a keypress (because it probably is).  Lemme check--Yeah, alt-shift-X, then "T".  Easy enough?

There is also window/show view/other/java/JUnit that will give you a junit run bar in a window.  You can then just hit the run tests button and it will run all the tests in your project/section.

Ctrl-shift-L is great for figuring out keybindings if you are getting to know eclipse.

Also, get VERY familiar wtih ctrl-space, just press it whenever you're in the middle of typing something (seriously, try it with everything!)  Also type "sysout[ctrl-space]"

Comment: @BillK: save two more keypresses "syso[CTRL + SPACE]" :)

Answer (score 1):

I've used the [testNG](http://testng.org) which has a plug in for [eclipse](http://code.google.com/p/testng-eclipse/).

Answer (score 1):

JUnit 4 is actually really easy to use, as long as you're using a project that targets Java 5 or newer, and have added it to the project.

I mean, how much easier can you get than

```
@Test
public myTest() {
    // Test code here
}
```

There are also `@Before`, `@After`, `@BeforeClass`, `@AfterClass`, and `@Ignore`.  The *Class methods need to be static methods.  `@Before` runs before each test, `@BeforeClass` runs before the first test... but keep in mind that JUnit tests can run in any order.

If you're doing database tests, you may want to look into the [DBUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/) addon, although you need to take some [special steps](http://www.testearly.com/2006/07/23/dbunit-with-junit-4/) to use it with JUnit 4's native mode.

Answer (score 1):

fit (http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=39417)

dbunit (http://www.dbunit.org/)

many others

in eclipse, you can right click a package and select run as a junit test.

be careful of http://xunitpatterns.com/test%20fixture%20-%20ambiguous.html. iirc, this boils down to junit creating an instance of each test case before calling setup and nunit just creating one instance.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean with "make using JUnit any easier"?

I use Ant for runnings tests as a task. Output will be stored into a flat file or a html file. It depends on the TestRunner.

Please specify your question and you'll get answers! :)